# EF Core | How to configure relationship between 3 entities?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have 3 entities:

BaseEntity

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

User

```
public class User : BaseEntity
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string LastName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public ICollection<Company> Companies { get; set; }
    public Property Properties { get; set; }
}
```

Company

```
public class Company : BaseEntity
{
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public Property CompanyProperties { get; set; }
}
```

Property

```
    public class Property : BaseEntity
    {
        public Dictionary<string, object> Properties {get; set;} = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }
```

The result must be: User has a collection of Company and one Property. Company has one user (company owner) and one Property. Property has a dictionary (ef core doesn't support it as i know)

Property class is for a user click '+' and inputs his own property

How to configure it using FluentAPI or data annotations?

Comment: `User` and `Company` has `ICollection<Property> Properties`. In turn, `Property` has `string Key`, `string Value`.

Answer (score 1):

The first caveat I suspect will be the desire to store `object` to cover strings, numeric values, etc. AFAIK this isn't really supported or would be efficient if you want to ever query against the values. You will invariably run into issues comparing strongly typed C# code through EF queries. If the data can store a number of different types then the typical practice is to store those all as easily parse-able strings.

There are a couple of different approaches you can use depending on how you intend to use these properties. If they are just values that you absolutely will not query against for either User or Company, then a simple option would be to store them as a delimited list string in their respective tables:

public class User
{
// ....

```
public string Properties { get; set; }

private ICollection<string>? _propertyList = null;
[NotMapped]
public ICollection<string> PropertyList => _propertyList ??= Properties.Split('~');
```

}

This would see the property list managed as a Tilde (~) delimited string, then using an unmapped accessor property to split it into a more useable collection. This would require explicit logic to get properties back into the delimited string in the case where you want to add/remove properties. A custom collection type that can expose a delimited string for the collection might be appropriate if editing these values. The limitation of this approach is that you cannot query against properties. For instance if you want all users that have a Property value of "Married", you cannot easily query the values. For instance you cannot write a query like:

```
var users = _context.Users
    .Where(x => x.PropertyList.Contains(property))
    .ToList();
```

The collection is unmapped so it cannot be parsed in queries. About the best you could do in this case would be to ensure that all property values are encased in "~" and the split ignores empty/null values: So instead of:

Married~WithChildren

you would have:

~Married~WithChildren~

Then searching would be possible using:

```
var users = _context.Users
    .Where(x => x.Properties.Contains("~" + property + "~"))
    .ToList();
```

This would not be an indexed query, so across a lot of rows and/or property values this would get rather slow.

A second option would be to consider a JSON typed property in the respective tables where the collection of property strings can be stored.  If your database engine and EF Provider supports JSON columns, you may even be able to query across the properties collection within the table rows. Again, this would not likely support indexing. I honestly haven't yet fully explored JSON column support in databases like SQL Server and PostgreSQL, so it is likely worth looking into as an option as this is something that has been relatively recently added in many DB providers.

The relational option would be to use a many-to-many relationship between Users, Companies, and Properties.

```
public class User : BaseEntity
{
    // ....

    public virtual ICollection<Property> Properties { get; set; } = new List<Property>();
}

public class Company : BaseEntity
{
    // ....

    public virtual ICollection<Property> Properties { get; set; } = new List<Property>();
}

public class Property : BaseEntity
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

When configuring EF, we tell it that User has many properties with many in return, as does Company. EF will manage a UserProperties table and a CompanyProperties table behind the scenes automatically if using CodeFirst, otherwise we can create these tables explicitly and tell EF to use them:

```
builder.Entity<User>()
    .HasMany(x => x.Properties)
    .WithMany()
    .UsingEntity("UserProperties");
builder.Entity<Company>()
    .HasMany(x => x.Properties)
    .WithMany()
    .UsingEntity("CompanyProperties");
```

The table would just contain a UserId + PropertyId and a CompanyId + PropertyId PK/FKs respectively. We don't need to declare the UserProperties or CompanyProperties as entities at all.

This solution is normalized and we can index and query across users or companies by property values efficiently.

An alternative you might commonly see would be to use something like a Properties table that looks something like this:

```
PropertyId
PropertyValue
OwnerType
OwnerId
```

Where OwnerType would be something like "User" or "Company" and the OwnerId would point to the respective Id in either of the two tables.

This is a de-normalized table relationship, and should be avoided because you cannot leverage indexes or constraints effectively to enforce the relationships between the 3 table relationship. For instance the OwnerId cannot be part of a FK relationship with either User or Company since a FK cannot point to two tables. It likely originated when disk space was expensive but still seems to be popular by developers that have an aversion to using two or more "similar" tables.